# Jquery/Javascript giving one class of four buttons four different random numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, random

I have 4 buttons and I want to make each button generate a random number when clicked on. The random numbers are generating with a for loop and math.random but I  assign it to my class and since the class is the same on all the buttons all 4 buttons only get one of the numbers but when I console log it there are 4 random numbers appearing

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)+1;
   console.log(random);
    var crystal= $(".diamond");
    crystal.attr({
        "data-random": random    
    });
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
<button class="diamond" id="red" >Red</button>
<button class="diamond" id="blue"> Blue </button>
<button class="diamond" id="yellow">Yellow</button>
<button class="diamond" id="green">Green</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have 4 buttons and I want to make each button generate a random
>   number when clicked on.

`crystal.attr` will set the same attribute to all the matches.

You need to replace this line

```
var crystal= $(".diamond");
```

with

```
var crystal= $(event.currentTarget);
```

or

```
var crystal= $( this );
```

Or if you want to **generate 4 new random numbers at every click** and assign one to all of them then use `each`

```
$(".diamond").each( function(){
   var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)+1;
   $(this).attr({
        "data-random": random    
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing `var crystal= $(".diamond");` it means variable crystal will have all elements with className 'diamond'

What you want is specific element at that index...So you can do that with jQuery `eq()` function.

All you need to do is

Replace this

```
var crystal= $(".diamond");
```

with this

```
var crystal= $(".diamond").eq(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you were iterating, calculating randoms and setting the value was not correct.

- Loop over all the elements with class `.diamond`
- Generate a random number in the each iteration.
- Set the attribute of `this` element.

```js
var crystal = $(".diamond");
crystal.each(function() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1;
  console.log(random);
  $(this).attr({
    "data-random": random
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="diamond" id="red">Red</button>
  <button class="diamond" id="blue"> Blue </button>
  <button class="diamond" id="yellow">Yellow</button>
  <button class="diamond" id="green">Green</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will do an `implicit interation` for you when you run,

```
crystal.attr({
    "data-random": random    
})
```

Because `crystal` include multi elements.

So for every `for` iteration, you will run 4 times inner iteration, that is set 4 times attributes for the same number.

```js
      var crystal= document.querySelectorAll('.diamond')
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(crystal, cr => {
        let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1
        cr.setAttribute('data-random', random)
      })
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
    <button class="diamond" id="red" >Red</button>
    <button class="diamond" id="blue"> Blue </button>
    <button class="diamond" id="yellow">Yellow</button>
    <button class="diamond" id="green">Green</button>
</div>
```